# Angular 4/5 file upload or image upload to Amazon S3

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement file upload in my MEAN app. My backend (Node and Express) and frontend (Angular) was deployed separately. What I need is to upload the file to amazon s3 through Angular, get the address destination after successful upload then save the file destination to a variable.

Is there any easy way to implement this? Let's say I have a form like this

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="file" id="myImage" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>
    <hr>

   <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar perfil</button>
   </div><br>
</form>
```

Then this code would be on my component (just for testing that I can get the file)

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        'myImage': null
    });
}


onFileChange(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.get('myImage').setValue({
                filename: file.name,
                filetype: file.type,
                value: reader.result.split(',')[1]
            })
        };
    }
}

onSubmit() {
    const formModel = this.form.value;
    this.loading    = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(formModel);
        alert('Finished uploading');
        this.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

[image]

How would I send the file from my form to Amazon S3? Then get the file destination in amazon s3 so I can save it to my database for fetching it later. I'm also not sure If should I create the amazon s3 configuration to my backend or frontend, I'm so confused right now.

Comment: what is your backend ??

Comment: I believe you will need to have a backend method that will handle the AWS S3 file upload.

Comment: It can be done from the browser.

Comment: @TomaszKula it is not secure to do it on the front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AWS SDK for JavaScript.

You can see the example of uploading the photo [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html#s3-example-photo-album-adding-photos).

```
function addPhoto(albumName) {
  var files = document.getElementById('photoupload').files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return alert('Please choose a file to upload first.');
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var fileName = file.name;
  var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '//';

  var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + fileName;
  s3.upload({
    Key: photoKey,
    Body: file,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
    }
    alert('Successfully uploaded photo.');
    viewAlbum(albumName);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there's not much tutorial regarding this with Angular 4/5 and Node for file upload to Amazon s3. I'll try using this approach and set up necessary AWS credentials and security.

Answer (score 4):

If you can, try to avoid using AWS SDK in the browser since you won't be able to rate limit the usage. Or worse you can expose your AWS credentials, if you store access key on the front-end.

Instead, use AWS SDK in your node.js backend and expose an API as a proxy. See https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/.

Comment: I already set up **AWS SDK** on my **node backend** but for testing purposes I used an **EJS templating engine** but it uses **multer-s3** to support file upload. If I can use the middleware I created in node that will handle the request from angular  that would be good. Thank you for your insights, I'll try experimenting more regarding this.